# press two times esc for close popup

Tags: jquery, html

I have two popup one show info with fancybox=second popup.
when fancybox is open en press esc its close my both popup.
now i want when fancybox is open en press esc that only fancybox close en than only my info popup is showed and press for the second time esc for close that popup.
this is my code for close the info popup the other for fancybox is plugin.

thx for helping me

```js
$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
       $('.popup').fadeOut(350);
       $("body").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="popup">
                <div class="popup_inner">
                   <div class="close"></div>
                   <div id="left">
                       <a href="images/<?php echo $project['foto']; ?>" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                           <img src="images/<?php echo $project['foto']; ?>" alt="">
                           <h2>Klik om meer te zien</h2>
                           <div id="overlay"></div>
                       </a>
                       <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `foto's` WHERE projecten_id = ?";
                            $popups = DB::getResult($sql, $_GET['id']);
                            foreach($popups as $popup){
                        ?>
                       <div class="hidden">
                           <a class="fancybox" href="images/<?php echo $popup['foto']; ?>"></a>
                       </div><!-- HIDDEN -->
                       <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                   </div><!-- LEFT -->
                    <div id="right">
                        <h1><?php echo $project['titel']; ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo $project['info']; ?></p>
                        <a class="link" href="<?php echo $project['link']; ?>" target="_blank">Bezoek website</a>
                    </div><!-- RIGHT -->
                </div><!-- POPUP_INNER -->
            </div><!-- POPUP -->
```

Comment: inlcude your html

Comment: The $(".popup") selector will apply a fadeout on all html tags that contains a popup class. 

To close only one off your popups, you have to change the way to identify your popups, using id's or couple of class.

Comment: @xmaster add html

Comment: @KevinGrosgojat is it not possible to press twice esc to close it?